# could somebody recommend me a professional camera DSLR?

Tags: dslr

I want buy a good DSLR, I have a digital and is not enough for me, I need to move forward to next step to the professional road. I'll appreciate yours recommends so much.
best

Thank so much for all the answer and recommends, I love take creatives photos of peoples, feel the scenarios, places, and be so near to the animals...
 But the really is that I have not much chance with that in my life, and suppose is more realistic a future taking photos to books of peoples and maybe for foodstyling. 
and I´m just to begin a photography classes to control technics and open my mind

thank you again!!!

Comment: The gear is the easy part. The skills is the much harder part. 

You could choose Canon Rebel series, or the equivalent in Nikon; or the mirrorless lineups in Sony, Fuji, or Olympus - for your purposes right now, they'll have more features than you need.

Canon / Nikon would have lots of existing lense, while mirrorless camera could be more compact and the EVF would be useful. 

Invest more in sharpening your skills.

FYI have a look at what kind of questions are expected here: https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to buy first after getting the first DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17946/what-to-buy-first-after-getting-the-first-dslr)

Comment: pick the most expensive one. But seriously, it is better to ask: "what factors should i consider when buying serious DSLR? I want to take pictures of X, Y, Z." Camera market changes very quickly for any recommendation to stay relevant for long

Comment: Questions seeking specific product or service recommendations, where the answer is likely to be either entirely personal or short-lived as a result of changing markets, are off topic here. Please rephrase your question tailored to you so we can try give an answer.

Comment: You may find this question and the answers useful: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/92119/what-kind-of-camera-do-i-get-for-my-class/92175#92175

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What kind of camera do I get for my class?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/92119/what-kind-of-camera-do-i-get-for-my-class)

Answer (score 2):

> ...and I´m just to begin a photography classes to control technics and open my mind...

Many basic photography courses have specific requirements about what type of camera and lens you must use for the course. Perhaps you should investigate what the course you plan to take requires before you select a camera for purchase?

Comment: I asked them, but like it is not a requirement to take the course, they don't suggest any one
 I´m very lost about which to buy. Because I don´t know nothing about DSLR and I live in Argentina and is very expensive and difficult buy one, but I have one opportunity because a person I know travel to USA and that is my chance to buy it. For this that is too important to me buy the correct one.  I don´t know if in the future I’ll can buy other one.
I appeciate all your help

Answer (score 0):

You need a Canon EOS 1D. They're getting very hard to find these days, but you can pick one up for only $400 bucks in like-new condition. [Here's the wiki on 'em](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS-1D).

This behemoth comes with 4 MEGA pixels - they're way tougher than the wimpy little pixels that make up the youthful cameras you see around today.

It also has a CCD sensor - that's short for Creatively Charged Device. This camera will literally make you more creative - and will charge from your creativity AT THE SAME TIME. This circle goes around and around until you feel like Ansel Adams trippin' on LSD. All creativity - full color, baby.

---

Addendum: Please don't take any of this post seriously. Please do, however, read [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). We can help you find products, but only after you've outlined what your current gear is, why it doesn't work for you, what problem you're looking to solve, etc.

Cheers - and welcome to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know exactly what you want to shoot and your exact budget it is hard to make a definitive choice. The lenses you get will affect the type of photos you can shoot as much if not more than the camera body itself.

If you've only being shooting with compacts and not 100% sure of what your needs are I would recommend getting the cheapest DSLR from a quality brand and invest in a couple of good lenses and once you have some experience with it you will be able to say "I need this feature" or "the performance in this area is holding me back" and then get your next DSLR which has what you need.

As a starting point a Canon 40D and a 50mm f1.8 lens (Yongnuo make an excellent 50mm that performs better than the canon for much less). Then a wide angle or telephoto lens depending on what you are shooting. You should be able to keep on using the lenses after you upgrade the body. The 40D + 50mm should cost you under £150/$200 which will mean you have not spent a lot to learn to master a DSLR and have a better idea of what you need before you invest thousands.

Comment: How does the Yongnuo 50mm perform better than Canon's Nifty Fifty? For not much more money, you might as well go for the reliability of Canon rather than one that can just stop working at any time :)

Comment: @laurencemadill, I second this view. I can respect the 40D recommendation, but getting the Y will just teach you about knock-offs of old lens designs. The Canon 2x the cost of the Y, but still under $125. Worth it.

Comment: @Corey there's certainly an argument for cheaper alternatives, but the Yongnuo isn't better (a bit off topic but I spent £8GBP on a non-branded 10-stop ND filter to decide whether it's worth buying a proper Lee Big Stopper, it turns out it's not 10-stop but somewhere close enough, but it allowed me to experiment, and the results were good enough for my messing around). The 40D is certainly great, my previous camera was a secondhand 40D

Comment: @Corey I use both the Canon and Yongnuo for teaching students and the sharpness and focus speed of the Yongnuo is noticeably better. However, the main benefit is to get the starter lens cheaper as it may not be what they use long term if they decide that most of what they do is macro or wide angle so why pay twice as much for a lense that independent reviews (and my own personal testing) has no added benefit.

Comment: @Corey but I do agree when you get your Pro lens it is totally worth getting a Canon L series rather than knock-offs or alternative brands - the difference is remarkable.

Comment: @David, For sure. It's incredibly hard to make equipment rec's without knowing more about OP though - so, it may be that cheap entry into the field is required, or it may not be. Until they edit this question...we'll never know. (My first lens was a Sig 28-105 f/2.8-4. Worked perfectly well for film, but it's lacking for digital. You're a nice teacher. I stick people with a K1000 and a 50mm f/1.7 :-D )

Comment: @Corey yes it is one of those impossible to answer questions but I based my answer on the fact they'd never owned a DSLR and what I thought I needed before I got my first DSLR was completely different to what I use now professionally so wish I had spent less to start with until I knew what I was doing. My first lense was a Tamron 18-270mm super zoom - amazing range of focal length but never took a really sharp photo and not great for for low-light or shallow depth of field.

Comment: @David Are you comparing the older EF 50mm f/1.8 II or the newer EF 50mm f/1.8 STM (which performs better than the older lens) to the Yongnuo that is a copy of the older lens?

Comment: @michael Clark I mean the old EF 50mm f/1.8 II the STM should be better but I've not got my hands on one yet.

Comment: There's no should be about it. It is better than both the EF50mm f/1.8 II and the EF 50mm f/1.4 at common apertures.