# What are good online or DVD tutorials for my new DSLR?

Tags: learning, nikon-d7000, tutorial

I recently purchased Nikon D7000 and would like to learn how to use it properly and want to learn photography using it. Can anyone suggest good online tutorials which I can look at or any DVDs which I can purchase?

Comment: How did you get on with your new DSLR? Found this site offering a free course if it would be of any help :) <http://lumusphoto.com>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this website from Nikon. It contains an interactive digital tutorial on how to use the D7000. It should be helpful in learning about your new camera.

[Nikon D7000 Digital Tutorial](http://www.nikondigitutor.com/eng/d7000/index.html)

Answer (score 8):

The "best" answer to your question is not going to provide a full tutorial of the D7000 and how to use it.  I would recommend **becoming familiar with basic photography techniques and skills**, then simply reading the manual or the Magic Lantern guide on your specific model if you have any questions on the actual execution of the techniques you are interested in.

Some recommended materials:

**[Magic Lantern Guides](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1454701323)** -  which are a series of books that can help you get familiar with a new camera.

**[Blue Crane DVD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004JHY3X0)** - might be an example of a DVD that you are looking for.  Most would say that these are somewhat basic, but I don't think you will find very advanced material on specifically the Nikon D7000, instead you will find general photography DVS.

**[DPReview](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/nikond7000/)** - A great free online "tutorial" of the in's and out's of that model can be found on dpreview.

Other similar questions on the basics that have been asked before:

[How to start the basics of photography, which is the best entry level SLR camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/how-to-start-the-basics-of-photography-which-is-the-best-entry-level-slr-camera)

[How to start learning photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-start-learning-photography)

[What are good resources for a beginning photographer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/what-are-good-resources-for-a-beginning-photographer)

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered [FroKnowsPhoto.com](http://froknowsphoto.com/beginners/), a great and very educational online video blog.  The videos are very well done and entertaining.  There is a whole serious on setting up and using the D7000.  The introductory video goes through each button and setting available.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Karl Taylor's](http://www.karltaylorphotography.co.uk/photography-tips-dvds.htm) range of DVDs. They are fantastic

Comment: Could you explain a little bit about what makes them fantastic?

Answer (score 0):

There is an immense wealth of information on Nikon USA's website at ... http://www.nikonusa.com/Learn-And-Explore/index.page .. in both text/image and video format.

Comment: Not sure why someone voted this down. Seems like a fine suggestion to me.

Comment: Thanks mattdm, I am always careful to only enter helpful information and had wondered why myself.

Comment: Nikon USA also provides a free and handy [iPhone App](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/nikon-learn-explore-photo/id330046127?mt=8) to learn on the go, featuring the same content as on their website.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be a specific 'tutorial' per se, but Thom Hogan has some pretty highly repsected manuals.  He explains the specifics about how each of the Nikon bodies work in great detail.  Each of the settings and controls are discussed and the effect they will have on your images.

They can be found at: http://www.bythom.com/